# GRUB - Fedora and Ubuntu on different drives

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I normally ran dualboot Ubuntu/Windows and recently decided to try adding Fedora to the list. I'm a bit confused about several things regarding grub, what the arrangement should be, and why a few things are happening.

Everything is EFI (not MBR)

**My initial setup**

NVME:

- 1 windows recovery
- 2 EFI
- 3 windows C:
- 4 Ubuntu /

SSD:

- 1 storage(ntfs)

**Changes after installing Fedora**

SSD:

- 1 storage(ntfs)
- 2 EFI
- 3 Unallocated 1GB ?? (might be the something with the partition editor during Fedora install)
- 4 Fedora /

1. Isn't ideal that OS's drive has its corresponding EFI partition on it?
2. Why did Ubuntu's Grub NOT detect Fedora while Fedora's grub detected Ubuntu?
3. Why is grub-customizer in Fedora not detecting Fedora?
4. Should I configure Fedora's install to NOT create an ESP on the SSD and just use the NVME's ESP? For example, Fedora's `/boot/EFI` points to the NVME's ESP
5. Should Ubuntu's /boot and Fedora's /boot actually be the same partition?

I'm not really sure what other questions I should be asking to get a better understanding of a more 'ideal' multi-boot *while multi-drive* setup.

Comment: I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: @waltinator Ive been using simple dualboot with a single drive for while and even back into the MBR days. Its more specifically why Fedora/Ubuntu don't always detect eachother and what if theres multiple drives. I will clarify the question

Comment: @ProjectPaatt Have you tried to (manually) mount the Fedora partition in Ubuntu before running `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Post actual partitions, `sudo parted -l` If you have a bios_grub, you installed in old BIOS mode, not newer UEFI mode. Drives should only have one ESP per drive.